# url function showing only 1 row?

Tags: python

i am trying to create a gui which with file explorer to select csv file and the program will go through the file fetching the url from each row and performing a requests.get however i am getting only one row output as shown in the screenshot

[image]

code:

```
import csv
import requests
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser
from checkurl import url_status

@Gooey(program_name="My program")
def parse_args():
    UI = GooeyParser()
    UI.add_argument('data_file',
                        action='store',
                        widget='FileChooser',
                        help="Source Excel file")

    mainUI = UI.parse_args()
    return mainUI

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    input_file=args.data_file
    output= url_status(input_file)
    mainUI = parse_args()
    print(output)
```

function:

```
import requests
import csv


def url_status(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
        my_list = list(reader)
        for row in my_list:
            name, url = row
            response = requests.get(url)
            result = "{}: {}".format(name, response)
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you create the `result` object every time you enter the loop and assign it with the new result with this line `result = "{}: {}".format(name, response)` and you return only the last item.

You can create a list of results and return that and print the results in a loop.

```
def url_status(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
        my_list = list(reader)
        results = []
        for row in my_list:
            name, url = row
            response = requests.get(url)
            results.append("{}: {}".format(name, response))
        return results
```

And print the result one by one by iterating over the results list as:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    input_file=args.data_file
    output = url_status(input_file)
    mainUI = parse_args()
    for out in output:
        print(out)
```